# Merge rows in redshift db based on 1-5 values

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift like this:

| date | filter_name1 | filter_value1 | filter_name2 | filter_value2 | total_cases | total_spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | sex | male | state | Arizona | 15 | 123.1 |
| 2022-02-01 | sex | female | state | Ohio | 66 | 66.7 |
| 2022-02-01 | sex | male | state | Arizona | 12 | 54 |
| 2022-01-01 | sex | female | state | California | 11 | 121 |
| 2022-01-01 | sex | male | state | Arizona | 43 | 96.63 |

Now i would like to "merge" rows based on filter_values which number can vary from 1 to 5. I'd like to push all distinct dates into an array. It should also sum their total_cases and total_spent if the dates are equal and push them into an array in the same order as the date array. There can be more different dates than 2.

Expected output would be:

| date | filter_name1 | filter_value1 | filter_name2 | filter_value2 | total_cases (sum) | total_spent (sum) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01"] | sex | male | state | Arizona | [58, 12] | [219.73, 54] |
| ["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01"] | sex | female | state | Ohio | [0, 66] | [0, 66.7] |
| ["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01"] | sex | female | state | California | [11, 0] | [121, 0] |

I've come up with the query below, but I have no idea how to merge rows based by the filter_value(s).

```
select listagg(distinct date, ', ') within group (order by filter_value1) as date, 
listagg(distinct filter_value1) as filter_value1, 
listagg(distinct filter_value2) as filter_value2,  
SUM(total_spent) as total_spent from TABLE 
group by date, filter_value1, filter_value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform a GROUP BY and use LISTAGG() to combine values into lists.  Something like (conceptual):

```
select filter_value1, listagg(total_spent, ', ') within group as total_spent
from <table>
group by filter_value1;
```

You will need to group by the full list of columns and add the square brackets etc.  This should get you started.

Comment: Hey, yeah, thanks for answering @Bill. I've tried this a few times but I got stuck on grouping by dates. I wasn't able to "merge" them based on filter values and then push dates and total_spent into an array.

`select listagg(distinct date, ', ') within group (order by filter_value1) as date, 
listagg(distinct filter_value1) as filter_value1,  
listagg(distinct filter_value2) as filter_value2, 
SUM(total_spent) as total_spent
from TABLE
group by date, filter_value1, filter_value2;`

Comment: Sounds like you got this working.  If so, well done.  If not, ping again and I can help.

Comment: I got this working partially. But i cannot get it merged. With the query above i get dates separately, I need them in an array :(

Comment: So you just need to add the square brackets to the string ( '[' & ']' ) or you need to convert this to a super data type?

Comment: Based on the query above, I want to merge rows with the same filter_values. It doesn't have to be an array (can perhaps be a comma separated string), I just want them combined which I couldn't accomplish.

Comment: Oh, this is because you are grouping by date so there is only 1 date per group.   Remove "date" from the group by list and you should be closer.